# jQuery Cookie URL

Tags: jquery, cookies, back-button

I have this cookie `jQuery.cookie("previousUrl", window.location.href, {path:"/"});` to store the previous page url. How can I use this cookie as a window.location so that when a user clicks a "back button" it will take them to the page url set in the cookie?
Cheers,
Mike

Comment: just read cookies value and on window.back call window.location.href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get cookie value

```
var cookieVal = $.cookie('previousUrl');
```

then do

```
 window.location.href = cookieVal;
```

Comment: Thanks @chandresh_cool. This works pertaining to my question. For some reason though when the user clicks on a link the previousURL cookie stores the active link url and not the current page url. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: That is because your this function jQuery.cookie("previousUrl", window.location.href, {path:"/"}); stores the redirected url or the clicked url.

Answer (score 0):

In a `jQuery` try this :

```
$(window).unload( function () 
{
   // read cookies value and if its set then window.location.href = cookie value
}
```

In `javascript` :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   // read cookies value and if its set then window.location.href = cookie value
}
```